# Perspective of 3D objects in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, 3d, perspective

I drew a 3D wedge shape in Inkscape (see below). I want to create a stack of total 6 wedges. The top one is depicted in the picture. The second one is below it and turns 15 degrees clockwise about the red axis, the third one 30 degrees clockwise, and so on. The bottom wedge will have the pointy head away from viewers and the gray surface facing the viewers.

Please note:

1. The red line intersects the top wedge surface at its geometric center.
2. The gray surface is a trapezoid, not a rectangle. This is intentional.

The 6 wedges should be equally spaced. Is there a good way to do this in Inkscape? I tried a few things but didn't get anywhere.

[image]

Comment: Inkscape is not a 3D application. Use something else, like Blender for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have taken a massive construction problem if it's intended to be solved by drawing in 2D. It will take hours + a week before it for learning the construction tricks. But It's possible.

The easy way

Making it in any 3D program, even in a CAD program with no realistic materials nor photographic rendering gives the result in minutes.

Here's your stack; 2 copies seen from different directions.

[image]

ANY watching direction is possible with a single click with no redrawing and the image can be used either for drawing over in Inkscape or as well exported as ready to use 2D vector.

Comment: Hi tapesmoke. Great work! The stack on the left is close to what I needed. It sounds like a 3D drawing program is a must for this type of drawing? Which one do you recommend? I had 0 3D drawing experience, including CAD -- not an engineer.

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out.

Comment: @tcollar not a must. But first you need to be able to consider tedious work as being not hard.